# Changing data content on an Object Tag in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, object

I have an HTML page which contains an Object tag to host an embedded HTML page.

```
<object style="border: none;" standby="loading" id="contentarea" 
 width="100%" height="53%" type="text/html" data="test1.html"></object>
```

However, I need to be to change the HTML page within the object tag. The current code seems to create a clone of the object and replaces the existing object with it, like so:

```
function changeObjectUrl(newUrl)
{
    var oContentArea = document.getElementById("contentarea");
    var oClone = oContentArea.cloneNode(true); 
    oClone.data = newUrl; 

    var oPlaceHolder = document.getElementById("contentholder"); 
    oPlaceHolder.removeChild(oContentArea); 
    oPlaceHolder.appendChild(oClone); 
}
```

This seems a rather poor way of doing this. Does anyone know the 'correct' way of changing the embedded page?

Thanks!

**EDIT**: In response to answers below, here is the full source for the page I am now using. Using the setAttribute does not seem to change the content of the Object tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script language="JavaScript">
function doPage()
{
    var objTag = document.getElementById("contentarea");
    if (objTag != null)
    {
        objTag.setAttribute('data', 'Test2.html');
        alert('Page should have been changed');
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="Form1" method="POST">
<p><input type="button" value="Click to change page" onclick="doPage();" /></p>
<object style="visibility: visible; border: none;" standby="loading data" id="contentarea" title="loading" width="100%" height="53%" type="text/html" data="test1.html"></object>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The Test1.html and Test2.html pages are just simple HTML pages displaying the text 'Test1' and 'Test2' respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I finally achieved it. You can do

```
document.getElementById("contentarea").object.location.href = url;
```

or maybe

```
document.getElementById("contentarea").object.parentWindow.navigate(url);
```

The Object element also has a 'readyState' property which can be used to check whether the contained page is 'loading' or 'complete'.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Both `object.location` and `object.parentWindow` are undefined.

Answer (score 10):

This seems to be a browser bug, `setAttribute()` should work. I found this workaround, which seems to work in all browsers:

```
var newUrl = 'http://example.com';
var objectEl = document.getElementById('contentarea');
objectEl.outerHTML = objectEl.outerHTML.replace(/data="(.+?)"/, 'data="' + newUrl + '"');
```

Answer (score 10):

The above solutions did not work properly in Firefox, the Object tag doesn't refresh for some reason. My object tags show SVG images.

My working solution for this was to replace the complete Object node with a clone:

```
var object = document.getElementById(objectID);
object.setAttribute('data', newData);

var clone = object.cloneNode(true);
var parent = object.parentNode;

parent.removeChild(object );
parent.appendChild(clone );
```

Comment: The reason why object content doesn't refresh is that removing value from data attribute doesn't clear document created by object element in the window. If the origin is different (i.e. opening files in the window) you don't have access to contents of that window because of security reason. So removing entire tag makes sense and recreate again whenever needed. That's why this solution totally works. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You can do it with [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.setAttribute)

```
document.getElementById("contentarea").setAttribute('data', 'newPage.html');
```

EDIT: 
It is also recommended that you use the window.onload to ensure that the DOM has loaded, otherwise you will not be able to access objects within it.

It could be something like this:

```
function changeData(newURL) {
    if(!document.getElementById("contentarea")) 
        return false;
    document.getElementById("contentarea").setAttribute('data', newURL);
}

window.onload = changeData;
```

You can read more about window.onload [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.onload)

Comment: I can't get this to work at the moment for some reason. The object still displays the old page. I will post the full HTML page I am using later if I don't have any Eureka moments.

Comment: But is the selector working? If you alert(document.getElementById("contentarea")) what does it say? If it says Undefined, then the DOM is not loaded. You should use document.onload. I will add it in my answer because the characters here are not enough.

Comment: `setAttribute()` doesn't work for me either. The value does change in the dom inspector, but the rendered contents of the `<object>` tag does not update.

Comment: `setAttribute` worked like a charm!!  Though I was using this method to display a PDF document.

Comment: It worked for me in microsoft edge and safari, not in google chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I found a very simple solution that also works in Chrome. The trick is to make the object (or a parent element) invisible, change the data attribute, and then make the object visible again.

In the code below, it is assumed that object_element is the object element and parent_element is the parent, and url is the url of the data.

```
parent_element.style.display = 'none'; // workaround for Chrome
object_element.setAttribute('data', url);
parent_element.style.display = '';
```

Answer (score 1):

Following user2802253, I use this one on Safari and Firefox, which also forces a redraw. (sorry, not enough reputation to post as a simple comment).

```
theObject.style.visibility = null;
theObject.setAttribute("data", url);
theObject.style.visibility = "visible";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 var obj = document.getElementById("pdfDoc");
 obj.setAttribute('data', newPdf);
```

worked on Chrome version 54 and Safari, but didn't work on IE 11

what worked on them all

```
 var obj = document.getElementById("pdfDoc");
 obj.setAttribute('data', newPdf);
 var cl = obj.cloneNode(true);
 var parent = obj.parentNode;
 parent.removeChild(obj);
 parent.appendChild(cl);
```

Answer (score 1):

This snippet did the job in my case

```
  var object = document.getElementById(objectID);
  object.setAttribute('data', newData);

  var clone = object.cloneNode(true);
  var parent = object.parentNode;

  parent.removeChild(object );
  parent.appendChild(clone );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id='myob'>
<object style="border: none;" standby="loading" id="contentarea" 
 width="100%" height="53%" type="text/html" data="test1.html"></object>
</div>
```

$('#myob').html($('#myob').html());

Answer (score 0):

Changing the data attribute should be easy. However, it may not work perfectly on all browsers.

If the content is always HTML why not use an iframe?

Comment: I am told by my project leader, The iframe element is not supported in HTML 4.1 Strict DTD and in XHTML 1.0 Strict DTD and so he doesn't want to use them, the big meanie.

Answer (score 0):

Antoher way of doing it, you could embed the object in a DIV

```
var newUrl = 'http://example.com';
var divEl = document.getElementById('divID');
var objEl = document.getElementById('objID');
objEl.data = newUrl;
// Refresh the content
divEl.innerHTML = divEl.innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a better way to achieve your objective.

Html:

```
<div id="mytemplate"><div>
```

Js:

```
function changeTemplate(t){
var mytemplate = document.getElementById("mytemplate");
mytemplate.innerHTML = '<object type="text/html" data=' + t + '></object>';
}
changeTemplate('template.html');
changeTemplate('whatever.html');
```

Comment: It doesn't work enough! Sorry, but I set minus that answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var content_area = document.getElementById("contentarea");
    content_area.data = newUrl;
```

Refreshes object in Chrome Version 42.0.2311.90 m

Answer (score 0):

the main reason of this issue is using "/" in local files.

> The Wrong Code :

```
 var obj = document.getElementById("hostedhtml");
 obj.setAttribute('data', "pages\page2.html");
```

> The Right Code :

```
 var obj = document.getElementById("hostedhtml");
 obj.setAttribute('data', "pages\\page2.html");
```