# Setting new data on <object>

Tags: jquery, html, object

I have an issue with using `<object>`.
I need it to show different external pages, but it's not really working for me. It is like, after the first time I set Data, changing it does nothing.
Do I need to refresh it, somehow?

This is my jQuery code to change the data:

```
$("#content").attr('data', urls[urlIdx]);
```

And my object:

```
<div id="Main" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
    <object id="content" style="width:100%;height:100%;"/>
</div>
```

Simple stuff.

`urls` is an array of urls, and `urlIdx` is a counter that I increment.

Edit:
I have made this jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/fJQm6/

Basically, the first time the tick executes, the object's data is set, but the subsequent ticks changes nothing.

Comment: Can you be more specific on was exactly you Aare trying to acheieve or what error you are getting while doing it?

Comment: Can you post all the relevant code? have you tried `data` method?

Comment: I have added a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible duplicate of 
[Changing data content on an Object Tag in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676705/changing-data-content-on-an-object-tag-in-html)

```
var divEl = document.getElementById('Main');
var objEl = document.getElementById('content');
objEl.data = newUrl; //you can use aray logic here
// Refresh the content
divEl.innerHTML = divEl.innerHTML;
```

using Jquery

```
$("#content").attr('data', urls[urlIdx]);
var $mainDiv=$("#Main");
$mainDiv.html($mainDiv.html());
```

Here is updated live jsfiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/fJQm6/3/

Answer (score 0):

First off, `object` is for embedded things like video etc. see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_object.asp)

What you might want to use instead is a `iframe` [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)

```
<iframe id="test" src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
```

You could then use jquery to set attr.

```
$('#test').attr('src','http://www.google.co.uk');
```

**Update**

`Object` can be used for webpages but `iframe` is preferred.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fJQm6/2/) updated with iframe.

Comment: I was kind of doing this, to avoid using an iframe. Is it not possible? Is iframe the only way?

Comment: As it happens w3c does suggest its possible and you fiddle seems to works sort of in chrome, however why avoid a iframe?

Comment: Some of the stuff we want to show, is burndown graphs from TFS. They don't want to display in iframes.