# HTML Object tag 'data' attribute wont update with jQuery change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As you can see from this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cYxy7/1/

I am using jQuery to change the 'data' attribute of an object tag. However, even though I am able to change the data attribute in the source code, the actual data stream of the object doesn't change and the same video is played. Does anyone know a fix?

I have tried a few 'refresh' techniques and none have worked so far.

HTML:

```
<object data="currentURL"></object>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click', "button#switch", function() {
    $( "object" ).attr("data", newURL);
});        
})
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing data content on an Object Tag in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676705/changing-data-content-on-an-object-tag-in-html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

I found out something even stranger. Changing the params does not work until you change the box model of the object:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click', "button#switch", function() {

    $( 'object param[name="flashvars"]' ).attr("value", "hostname=www.twitch.tv&channel=liquidwifi&auto_play=true&start_volume=25");

     $( "object").attr('data',  "http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=liquidwifi").hide().show(); 

});        
})
```

this perfectly works: http://jsfiddle.net/W7NTd/1/

---

For some strange reason changing the param values didnt work, only creating new html seems to work for me:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click', "button#switch", function() {
        $('object param[name="flashvars"]').attr('value', $('object param[name="flashvars"]').attr('value').replace('ivan', 'liquidwifi'));
        var new_html = $('#wrapper').html();
        $('#wrapper').html(new_html);
    });        
})
```

I added a wrapper for that.

[See the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cYxy7/4/)

Answer (score 2):

The following code works for me

```
$( "object" ).replaceWith('<object data="' + newURL + '"></object>');
```

Answer (score 0):

The flash object is quite trickie  to reload.

Try using this simple [flashloader](http://jquery.lukelutman.com/plugins/flash/) or [SWFObject](http://jquery.thewikies.com/swfobject/examples).

Comment: you should provide some code example than just pointing to libs

Answer (score 0):

You need to update a parameter and then the data attribute:

```
$( "object param[name=flashvars]" ).attr("value", "hostname=www.twitch.tv&channel=liquidwifi&auto_play=true&start_volume=25");
$( "object").css('display', 'none');
$( "object").attr('data',  "http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=liquidwifi").css('display', '');
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/W7NTd/2/

Answer (score 0):

Append this in your code. this might help.

```
 $("object param[name=flashvars]").attr("value", $("object").attr("data"));
```

Answer (score -2):

the reason is that you are not changing the param value

While changing the object attr change the param flashvars value also

demo here :
    http://jsfiddle.net/cYxy7/3/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').on('click', "button#switch", function () {
        alert("The object's 'data' attritube is currently: " + $("object").attr("data"));
        $("object").attr("data", "http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=liquidwifi");
        $("param[name='flashvars']").attr("value", "hostname=www.twitch.tv&channel=liquidwifi&auto_play=true&start_volume=25");
        alert("The object's 'data' attribute is now: " + $("object").attr("data"));
    });
})
```

cheers!