# How can I access the content of a dynamically created object tag in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been searching for an answer for this problem for several hours and I can't seem to find any solutions that work. I have created a dynamic object tag using jquery and set its data to another page on my website. I appended the object tag to a div and the div to the body of my page. What I want to do is access the html of the page that I set as the data of my object tag in order to monitor for changes on that page and update my current page based on those changes. When defining the object tag in html, I can access its contents using the contentDocument property of the object tag but when generating the tag dynamically, contentDocument is undefined. I've also tried using the contents function of jquery but it returns an object of length 0. Here is basically what I've tried:

This is the code for my page test.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function test()
        {
            var parentDiv = document.createElement("div");
            $(parentDiv).addClass("parentDiv");
            var object = $("<object>");
            $(object).attr("id","objectId");

            $(parentDiv).append(object);

            $("body").append(parentDiv);
            $(object).attr("data","test2.html");
            $(object).addClass("object");

            // These give errors
            var content = object.contentDocument;
            alert(content.getElementById("div"));
            var content = $(object).contents();
            alert(content.length());

            /* THIS WORKS IF object defined as a tag in HTML body

            var content = document.getElementById("objectId").contentDocument;
            alert(content.getElementById("div").innerHTML);
            */
        }
    </script>   
</head>
<body onload="test()">
<!-- <object id="objectId" data="test2.html"></object> -->
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the code for the page of the object data test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test 2</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="div" style="width:200px;height:200px;background-color:red">
       DIV Contents
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: why do you need that? for click events etc?

Comment: The page I need in the object tag is like an alert monitor and will be changing constantly. I need to be able to see when there is an alert and also perform some action on my page when an alert occurs.

Answer (score 0):

At this moment, it is a jQuery object. So you need to define it:

```
// Replace it like this:
var content = document.getElementById("objectId").contentDocument;
var content = object.contentDocument;
alert(content.getElementById("div"));
var content = $(object).contents();
alert(content.length());
```

Or you can also use like:

```
// Replace it like this:
var content = $("#objectId").get(0).contentDocument;
var content = object.contentDocument;
alert(content.getElementById("div"));
var content = $(object).contents();
alert(content.length());
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Praveen. Unfortunately, it still gives the same error in Chrome: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementById' of undefined

Comment: Isn't there any way to access the contents of a dynamically created object tag?

Comment: I mean, that is totally wrong!! What are you trying to do?

Comment: Use `content.find("div");` for the same.

Comment: Still the same error unfortunately. The content of the page test2.html is showing on my page but object.contentDocument returns undefined when trying to access elements on the external page. It works if the tag is not created dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a number of HTML/Javascript concepts mixed up. I've corrected your code to at least have no errors:

```
var parentDiv = document.createElement("div");
$(parentDiv).addClass("parentDiv");
var object = document.createElement("object");
object.setAttribute("id", "objectId");
object.innerHTML = "Hello, Earth!";

$(parentDiv).append(object);

$("body").append(parentDiv);
object.setAttribute("data", "test2.html");
$(object).addClass("object");

var content = document.getElementById("objectId");
alert(content.innerHTML);
```

1. The jQuery '$' function, the same as the ['jQuery' function, which is an element **selector**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/), **not an element creator**. This code, `var object = $("<object>")` won't work because there does not exist an object on the page which is targeted by CSS selector `<object>`. I've changed that bit to `document.createElement("object")` instead.
2. As the `object` variable is now a DOM element, I've elected to use the `.setAttribute` function instead, which is a native DOM function.
3. `$("body").append(parentDiv)` will correctly add the `parentDiv` (and its child `object`) DOM element to the end of the `body` element. This allows `$(object).addClass("object")` to function properly.
4. The `contentDocument` property is exclusive to the [iFrame element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement). I've changed the property to innerHTML instead. The alert box correctly displays "Hello, Earth!" which is the contents of the `object` element.

[Working JSFiddle demo here.](https://jsfiddle.net/odecsofe/4/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply analytalica. But the problem is not with accessing the inner html of the object tag. I want to access the elements on the page  that was loaded into object variable (elements on test2.html). If I define the object tag directly in my body (not dynamically appending it), the contentDocument property works fine. Shouldn't there be a way to access the elements of an object tag's data page if the object variable is created dynamically like you did?

Comment: Have you seen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676705/changing-data-content-on-an-object-tag-in-html