# Reload the page with the <object > or <iframe> in a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried to create a link, if the link I click it on the <0bject> or < iframe > I make will change the appropriate link I click. And display the active link

**Example:**

This my link

> **Link :** A B C D
>
> < This my object load show >

If I click on the link A, the  will call a web page A.

```
<object width="1225px" height="1000px" data="http://webpage A/"></object>
```

And if I click B and then the object will call the < B > and so on .

```
<object width="1225px" height="1000px" data="http://webpage B/"></object>
```

In one page

**Example:**

```
<div class='konten'>
    <div class='tab'>
        <h1>EGLG Chr: 
        <a href ="http://10.88.25.48/sbc-portal/eglg_chr1> 
        <a href ="http://10.88.25.48/sbc-portal/eglg_chr2">2</a> 
        <a href ="http://10.88.25.48/sbc-portal/eglg_chr3">3</a> 
        <a href ="http://10.88.25.48/sbc-portal/eglg_chr4">4</a> 
        <a href ="http://10.88.25.48/sbc-portal/eglg_chr5">5</a> 
        <a href ="http://10.88.25.48/sbc-portal/eglg_chr6">6</a> 
        <a href ="http://10.88.25.48/sbc-portal/eglg_chr7">7</a> 
        <a href ="http://10.88.25.48/sbc-portal/eglg_chr8">8</a> 
        <a href ="http://10.88.25.48/sbc-portal/eglg_chr9">9</a> 
        <a href ="http://10.88.25.48/sbc-portal/eglg_chr10">10</a> 
        <a href ="http://10.88.25.48/sbc-portal/eglg_chr11">11</a> 
        <a href ="http://10.88.25.48/sbc-portal/eglg_chr12">12</a> 
        <a href ="http://10.88.25.48/sbc-portal/eglg_chr13">13</a> 
        <a href ="http://10.88.25.48/sbc-portal/eglg_chr14">14</a> 
        <a href ="http://10.88.25.48/sbc-portal/eglg_chr15">15</a> 
        <a href ="http://10.88.25.48/sbc-portal/eglg_chr16">16</a> 
        </br>
        </h1>
        <object width="1225px" height="1000px" data="reload if i click link"></object> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: @fuyushimoya ,I want when I click LINK : ABCD web appear on <object > the same in one page .

Comment: That's a statement, not a problem, Stackoverflow helps you solve problems, not a code writing service, you should at least post what you have tried so far. You can first take a look of [ask].

Comment: @fuyushimoya thanks for your advice , I forgot to show my script problems . I 've included a script problems please help .

Comment: looks like a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676705/changing-data-content-on-an-object-tag-in-html

Comment: @tocallaghan ,thanks but rather complicated to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the easiest way would simply be to change the attributes of the `<object>` tag or the `<iframe>` with JS / jQuery.

For example:

```
<a href="http://www.bing.com/" onclick="return false;">Bing</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$("a").click(function() {
    $("iframe").attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
});
```

See [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/0qwagseh/5/) (JSFiddle).