# Angular2 embedded object type binding not works

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular2-components

I have written an angular2 component to display embedded documents, but when I try to bind the mimetype of document it is not working.

**html:**

```
<div class="embed-responsive" *ngIf="mimeType!==null">
        <object [attr.data]="url" 
                [attr.type]="mimeType"
                class="embed-responsive-item">
                <embed [attr.src]="url"
                       [attr.type]="mimeType"/>
        </object>
</div>
```

**working html without type binding:**

```
<div class="embed-responsive" *ngIf="mimeType!==null">
        <object [attr.data]="url" 
                type="application/pdf" 
                class="embed-responsive-item">
                <embed [attr.src]="url"
                       type="application/pdf"/>
        </object>
</div>
```

**typescript code:**

```
import { Component, Input, HostListener } from "@angular/core";
import { AttachmentFile } from "../../model/dockModel";
import { DomSanitizer, SafeUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

    @Component({
        selector: "document-viewer-inline",
        templateUrl: "docview/components/document-viewer-inline-component/document-viewer-inline-component.html"
    })
    export class DocumentViewerInlineComponent {

        private attachment: AttachmentFile;

        public url: SafeUrl = null;
        public mimeType: string = null;

        constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
        }

        @Input()
        public set attachmentFile(f: AttachmentFile) {
            this.attachment = f;
            if (this.attachment !== null && this.attachment !== undefined) {
                this.url = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("/attachment/contentById/" + this.attachment.componentId);            
                this.mimeType = f.mimeType;
            }
        }

        public ngOnInit() {
            this.calculateInlineHeight();        
        }

    }
```

My question is: **how can I bind the type attribute of embedded and object?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found where it's explicitly stated but I'm pretty sure `<object>` doesn't support dynamic changes to the `type` attribute and requires it to be set statically.

See also [Changing data content on an Object Tag in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676705/changing-data-content-on-an-object-tag-in-html)

Below workaround doesn't work - see comments:

<strike>A hack could be</strike>

```
    <object *ngIf="mimeType!==null" [attr.data]="url" 
            [attr.type]="mimeType"
```

```
 constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {}

 private _mimeType:string=null;
 public get mimeType():string { return this._mimeType; }
 public set mimeType(value:string) {
   this._mimeType = null;
   this.cdRef.detectChanges();
   this._mimeType = value;
   this.cdRef.detectChanges();
 }
```

To make this more convenient to use you could wrap this with a custom `<my-object>` component.

**UPDATED hack:**

```
public showObject: boolean = true;
public url: String = null;
// public url: SafeUrl = null;

constructor(@Inject(DomSanitizer) private sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
            @Inject(ChangeDetectorRef) private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
}

@Input()
public set attachmentFile(f: FetAttachmentFile) {
    this.attachment = f;
    if (this.attachment !== null && this.attachment !== undefined) {
        this.url = null;
        this.mimeType = null;
        this.showObject = false;
        this.cdRef.detectChanges();
        this.url = "/attachment/contentById/" + this.attachment.componentId;
        // this.url = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("/attachment/contentById/" + this.attachment.componentId);
        this.mimeType = f.mimeType;
        this.showObject = true;
        this.cdRef.detectChanges();
    }
}

public innerHtml() {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml( 
        "<object data='" + this.url + "' type='" + this.mimeType + "' class='embed-responsive-item'>" +
        "<embed src='" + this.url + "' type='" + this.mimeType + "' />" +
        "</object>");
}
```

html code:

```
<div class="embed-responsive" 
     [style.height]="inlineHeight"
     *ngIf="showObject"
     [innerHTML]="innerHtml()">
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried it, but it says: `No provider for TemplateRef`

Comment: Sorry, I guess it's because you already have an `*ngIf` on your element. I somehow missed that.

Comment: now with this solution, I receive an error message from DI, I think it cannot inject ChangeDetectorRef

Comment: `Error in docview/components/document-viewer-inline-component/document-viewer-inline-component.html:1:8 caused by: No provider for TemplateRef!`

Comment: Sorry, no idea. Can you reproduce in a plunker?

Comment: I have solved the TemplateRef error, it was because of missing * before *ngIf

Comment: It seems that the above mentioned detectChanges() not solves this problem

Comment: if I use innerHtml it works: I put `public innerHtml() {
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml( 
        "<object data='" + this.url + "' type='" + this.mimeType + "' class='embed-responsive-item'>" +
            "<embed src='" + this.url + "' type='" + this.mimeType + "' />" +
            "</object>");
    }` to typescript and replaced the html code: `<div class="embed-responsive" 
     [style.height]="inlineHeight"
     *ngIf="showObject"
     [innerHTML]="innerHtml()">
</div>`

Comment: so it is partially good solution: "I haven't found where it's explicitly stated but I'm pretty sure <object> doesn't support dynamic changes to the type attribute and requires it to be set statically." it is true, but the mentioned hack not works.

Comment: Seems even with `*ngIf` the bound property is set only after the element itself is added to the DOM, while with your approach it is created already with the `type` property set which seems to be required for `<object>`.