# Disable view caching in if.bind?

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'm running into a strange issue with the `<object>` tag inside of an `if.bind`. Essentially, it seems as though the view fragment inside of the if binding is being cached. I've created a Gist with my findings on Gist.run, here:

https://gist.run/?id=e25a4e4ca1de59ba8baff20c3a4304c2

> Object tags do not appear to be re-rendered inside an if binding. This means that object content does not get refreshed when the if binding changes if fallback content has been inserted.
>
> 1. Change the size of the image below using the number input. If you change the number to zero, the image will be invalid and fallback content will appear.
> 2. Re-add the number. The content does not refresh. This is a [known bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676705/changing-data-content-on-an-object-tag-in-html).
> 3. However, toggling the content via if.bind does not reset the object itself (although the data should be re-bound). Is the view cached?

I'm not entirely sure what's causing this problem, but I believe that it may be due to Aurelia's caching. I believe that Aurelia isn't rebuilding the view every time the if binding reappears (although it is re-running the bindings). This means that the `<object>` is invalid and the fallback content is displayed. If this is the case, is there a way to disable caching for the `if` binding - perhaps through a binding behavior?

Comment: Wow this is old.  I can reproduce this too, perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem may actually be in the aurelia-bundle you are using, not in aurelia core. Your gist.run obviously shows the issue very well. The only reason I suspect this, is I just tried to reproduce the bug using aurelia-cli and updating the -bootstrapper and -tools to latest revs. Just copied your app.html and app.js straight from the gist.run. In aurelia-cli could not reproduce the same bug as you observed in gist.run. There are other differences too though :) For example the plateholder text does not appear, instead i see the placehold.it page in a scrolling div. Very strange. Anyways, I hope this answer helps you figure it out! Here is are the module versions I tested with.

```
$ npm list | grep aurelia
├─┬ aurelia-animator-css@1.0.1
│ ├── aurelia-metadata@1.0.2
│ ├── aurelia-pal@1.1.1
│ └─┬ aurelia-templating@1.1.4
│   ├── aurelia-binding@1.1.0
│   ├── aurelia-loader@1.0.0
│   ├── aurelia-path@1.1.1
│   └── aurelia-task-queue@1.1.0
├─┬ aurelia-bootstrapper@2.0.0
│ ├── aurelia-event-aggregator@1.0.1
│ ├── aurelia-framework@1.0.8
│ ├── aurelia-history@1.0.0
│ ├── aurelia-history-browser@1.0.0
│ ├── aurelia-loader-default@1.0.0
│ ├── aurelia-logging-console@1.0.0
│ ├── aurelia-pal-browser@1.1.0
│ ├── aurelia-polyfills@1.1.1
│ ├─┬ aurelia-router@1.1.0
│ │ └── aurelia-route-recognizer@1.1.0
│ ├── aurelia-templating-binding@1.1.0
│ ├── aurelia-templating-resources@1.2.0
│ └── aurelia-templating-router@1.0.1
├─┬ aurelia-cli@0.23.0
│ ├── aurelia-dependency-injection@1.2.0
├─┬ aurelia-testing@1.0.0-beta.2.0.1
│ └── aurelia-logging@1.2.0
├─┬ aurelia-tools@1.0.0
```

Comment: Good call. I updated my deps, but I'm still seeing the same thing. Strangely, you're seeing the website itself instead of the fallback content, which I don't think should happen. Try putting in an obviously invalid image URL and you should see the behavior I'm seeing.

Comment: Yep if I edit the data attribute to always be invalid URL, then I always see the placeholder text, but never anything else. Still cannot repro using Chrome55 on OS X, in the aurelia-cli context. But I am also not seeing the Step #2 bug, the known issue you reference. Your bug depends on that bug, in a sense. This is a strange one, you are right!

Comment: I confirmed your behavior locally as well. I think it may have to do with running from localhost as opposed to running from a server. Regardless, the main issue is that if once the fallback content is displayed for any reason (invalid URL, bad load, etc) removing and rebinding through the `if` binding doesn't seem to actually recreate that element in the DOM.

Comment: If you use "0" as the size value, you should receive the fallback content as placehold.it returns a 301 Moved Permanently response. The homepage loading within the object tag when running locally is a different issue.

Comment: Ahah ok confirmed, can reproduce the problem now. Oh well! Might be worth asking on https://gitter.im/aurelia/Discuss too if nothing pans out here.