# Javascript object source

Tags: javascript

I've edited my question to be more clear, the original question is below.

I'm a beginner at Javascript, currently starting to learn it. At W3School I saw an example of a code switching a lightbulb on and off. Here it is:

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_intro.asp

I've altered that code a bit, but it still works.

```
<script>
      function bulbOn() {
        document.getElementById('myImage').src='pic_bulbon.gif';
      }
      function bulbOff() {
        document.getElementById('myImage').src='pic_bulboff.gif';
      }
    </script>

    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="bulbOn()">Turn on the light</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="bulbOff()">Turn off the light</a>
    <img src="pic_bulboff.gif" width="100" height="180" id="myImage" style="width:100px">
```

Now instead of the lightbulb (which uses the html `<img>` tag I want to switch between two external html pages using the `<object>` tag. My question is how to do that.

I've noticed that `document.getElementById('myImage').src` doesn't work for objects, only for images. But if this doesn't work, then what does work?

Please don't come up with too complicated solutions, I'm still a beginner. Please describe your answer in a way I can understand it. No offense, but some of the answers given so far I simply don't understand.

This is what my original question looked like.

> I'm a beginner with Javascript, so please don't come up with too
>   complicated answers. I probably wouldn't understand them anyway.
>
> This is what I got so far:
>
> ```
>     <script>
>   function loadPage1() {
>     document.getElementById('myObject').innerHTML = "<object
>         data="page1.html" align="baseline" border="0" width="100%"
>         type="text/html" id="myObject"></object>";
>   }
>   function loadPage2() {
>     document.getElementById('myObject').innerHTML = "<object
>         data="page2.html" align="baseline" border="0" width="100%"
>         type="text/html" id="myObject"></object>";
>   }
> </script>
>
> <table border="0" width="100%">
>     <tr>
>         <td><a href="javascript:loadPage1()">Page 1</a></td>
>         <td rowspan="2"><p align="center"><object
>         data="page1.html" align="baseline" border="0" width="100%"
>         type="text/html" id="myObject"></object></p>
>         </td>
>     </tr>
>     <tr>
>         <td><a href="javascript:loadPage2()">Page 2</a></td>
>     </tr>
> </table>
> ```
>
> Obviously it isn't working, but I don't understand what I'm doing
>   wrong.
>
> I can't use the iframe tag because the server suppresses it (I don't
>   own the server, so I got nothing to say about it), so I have to use
>   the object tag instead.
>
> Who can help me out here?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Well, of course it's not working. You're setting the `innerHTML` of an `object` element to another `object` element. Instead, replace the HTML of a container element.

Comment: Can you please explain further because I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: "_Obviously it isn't working_" It is not obvious to me - you haven't told us what it is supposed to do or what it is actually doing. "_Who can help me out here?_" I might be able to but I'm not sure because I don't know what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: It's supposed to switch the source of an iframe between page1.html and page2.html. Only instead if iframe I'm using object for given reasons.

I've made two links, one for page 1 and one for page 2. The links do show, but the contents of the object don't change.

Comment: Well, with this code `getElementById('myObject').innerHTML = "<object></object>` you would end up with `<object><object></object></object>` which is not what you want probably.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing data content on an Object Tag in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676705/changing-data-content-on-an-object-tag-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script>
  function loadPage1() {
    document.getElementById('myObject').innerHTML = "<object
        data="page1.html" align="baseline" border="0" width="100%"
        type="text/html" id="myObject"></object>";
  }
  function loadPage2() {
    document.getElementById('myObject').innerHTML = "<object
        data="page2.html" align="baseline" border="0" width="100%"
        type="text/html" id="myObject"></object>";
  }
</script>

<table border="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="javascript:loadPage1()">Page 1</a></td>
        <td rowspan="2"><p align="center" id="myObject"><object
        data="page1.html" align="baseline" border="0" width="100%"
        type="text/html" ></object></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="javascript:loadPage2()">Page 2</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Your mistake is that you are changing the `innerHTML` of the object you want to change, so you end up with this after you click the button:

```
<object data="page1.html" id="myObject">
     <object data="page2.html" id="myObject"></object>
</object>
```

So because we don't want to change the inside of the `<object>` element, we should change the contents of the `<object>`'s parent, which in this case is the `<p>` element.

**Please note that if you have anything inside that `<p>` element, it will now get removed.**

Answer (score 0):

Create a div called div_target in your html body. Then change functions page1 & page2 to with the following code.

```
document.getElementById('div_target').innerHTML = ‘what ever you want’;
```